#  android passing intent data to new activity

Tags: android, video, android-intent

Ok activity 1 displays thumbnails of videos from the SD card in a gridVideoView. I want to be able to click and pass the data onto activity 2 and play those videos. My book that i bought only shows me how to do this with strings. How can i do this so when i click a video in activity 1 it is passed and can be played in activity 2?

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Editor.class);     intent.putExtra("mnt/sdcard-ext", _ID); startActivity(intent);

    private VideoView video;
    private MediaController ctlr;
    File clip=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
          "mnt/sdcard-ext");

  if (clip.exists()) {
  video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
  video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());

   ctlr=new MediaController(this);
   ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
   video.setMediaController(ctlr);
   video.requestFocus();
   video.start();
  }
}
```

}

How do i do reference the intent in the VideoView correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the ID to Activity 2 and is a Integer do...

int data=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("mnt/sdcard-ext");

Comment: Intent data = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Editor.class); data.putExtra("mnt/sdcard-ext", _ID); startActivity(data); – Activity 1  
 
int data = getIntent(data).getExtras() .getInt("mnt/sdcard-ext"); - Activity 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference it in the activity (the Editor activity). There use `getIntent()` to get the intent that triggered the activity, then look in the extras for your data.

Comment: `Intent data = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Editor.class);     
    data.putExtra("mnt/sdcard-ext", _ID); 
    startActivity(data);`

Comment: `int data = getIntent(data).getExtras()
         .getInt("mnt/sdcard-ext");`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have a static variable in the class that you pass the video to before opening the intent. Although this method can cause confusion and bugs if everyone on your team is not aware that the design pattern begin used.